# Where to put the unused states in synchronous counter that counts Even numbers?

Tags: counter

Suppose if we have a counter that counts only Even numbers and the unused states(odd numbers) treated as don't-care condition.

```
Current state           Next State
A  B  C  D              A  B  C  D
0  0  0  0              0  0  1  0
0  0  1  0              0  1  0  0
0  1  0  0              1  0  0  0
1  0  0  0              1  0  1  0
1  0  1  0              1  1  1  0
1  1  1  0              0  0  0  0

0  0  0  1              x  x  x  x
0  0  1  1              x  x  x  x
0  1  0  1              x  x  x  x
0  1  1  1              x  x  x  x
1  0  0  1              x  x  x  x
1  0  1  1              x  x  x  x
1  1  0  1              x  x  x  x
1  1  1  1              x  x  x  x
```

Above; I put the all unused states at the end.

Does this a right way? OR I must put them as normally as it's, like :

```
   Current state            Next State
    A  B  C  D              A  B  C  D
    0  0  0  0              0  0  1  0
    0  0  0  1              x  x  x  x
    0  0  1  0              0  1  0  0
    ........
```

Comment: Since it's the values which encode the operations, not the order on paper it wouldn't typically matter.  However, if you are doing a paper exercise in grouping like terms (such as in a Karnough map) you may for purposes of that need to list them in order; but a grey code order rather than a binary value one.  Of course if you have a class assignment or something else with style guidelines, that could impose requirements as well.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Yes, I am doing the paper exercise, it's the designation of *Synchronous Counter* subject, unfortunately; we don't have a practical, we only study the theoretical way.

After all, your comment were helpful, but didn't answered my question, sorry :)

Comment: Isn't it obvious that the "D" state variable is completely superfluous and should simply be eliminated?

Comment: @Azad - the answer is that it doesn't matter, unless there's a requirement you haven't told us about which would make it matter - I tried to explain a few possibilities along those lines.

Comment: @DaveTweed: No, since it's `2^4`, it needs `4` state variables.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Thanks, there is no requirement, it's only to be sure that I am not taking a wrong way of using one of the ways that I mentioned.

Comment: *What's* 2^4??? You only have 8 valid states, which is only 2^3. The "D" state variable is always 0, so you might as well eliminate it and tie it to ground instead.

Comment: @DaveTweed: if you notice the counter reaches number `14` in decimal which is (1110) in binary, so we have `4` bits, I am now confused about removing the `D`, it's right we didn't use it, but we need it in the state table.

Comment: The *output* for D needs to be zero, but it has no relevance as a state variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you perform a logic minimization analysis of the four state variables A, B, C, and D and take don't cares into consideration in the Karnough map groupings you will find that the D term minimizes away as the input to any of the state transfer equations. Also you will find that the logic equation for the drive of the Q(D) flop flop becomes:

Q(D) := 0